# Is there a way to identificate connected users while they chat with bot?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

So im new to IBM Watson assistant, and i am wondering, when i initialize session for a current usern who sent message, where should i store it, and how can i tell watson to make difference between session_id's of user1 and user2 for example?

Right now i tried using a global variable in nodejs, but as i said in that way i could not make a difference between sessions of multiple users.

````
const assistant = new WatsonAssistant({
  username: process.env.WATSON_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.WATSON_PASSWORD,
  url:      process.env.WATSON_URL,
  version: process.env.WATSON_VERSION

});


exports.getMessage = body => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

  // Initializing session for current user
  if(!global.session_id){
    const createdSessionId = await assistant.createSession({
      assistant_id: process.env.WATSON_ASSISTANT_ID
    });
    global.session_id = createdSessionId.session_id;
  }

  assistant.message(
    {
      workspace_id: process.env.WATSON_WORKSPACE_ID,
      input: { text: body.input },
      session_id: global.session_id,
      assistant_id: process.env.WATSON_ASSISTANT_ID
    },
    function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(response);
      }
    }
  );
});```

I would like to have session_id's of multiple users who have used my chatbot.
````

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using NodeJS Express as your web server, and then some Express session middleware to manage the user session (between the web browser and the server). An middleware I have used is "express-session".

For example I would do this:

```
const session = require('express-session');

// use unique value for secret, here using the bot workspace ID
app.use(session({secret: process.env.WORKSPACE_ID}));
```

You then have a "req.session" object you can store data on and retrieve in subsequent calls by the same user. You could store your Assistant session ID on this req.session object so that it is available. A different user will get a different express session and thus a different Assistant session.

The default implementation of "express-session" uses memory so as per their README you will want to use something such as disk or database for production purposes.

Comment: That could help but, i would like if user choose an option to send response based on interval. Also is WORKSPACE_ID different for each user? if not WORKSPACE_ID is not an unique value. For example bot should send a single message each 8 hours or each day